# Visual Studio 2017: Exe not found in path and or not being created

Tags: visual-studio, path, exe

I create a project (Tester) and placed it inside of a folder `C PRO` on my desktop. I create a file for C++ and fill it with basic code. Local debug later I get a message

`Unable to start program 'C:\User\(me)\Desktop\C PRO\Tester\Debug\Tester.exe' system cannot find file specified`

Comment: Did you check the path of interest to see if the `Tester.exe` is there or not? I think when you try to debug, it should compile and build automatically but may be it is not doing it so you might need to compile and build beforehand

Comment: Yes, i did. I found nothing within the path, infact the exe file doesn't exist on my computer at all.

Comment: What type of project did you create with C++ by Visual Studio ? Is it a UWP app or other ?